# How to create labels and levels for multiple variables from different data sets

Tags: r, label, levels

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4)
B <- c(2,1,3,1)
D <- c(3,1,2,1)
df_raw <- data.frame(A,B,D)

var <- c("A","B","D")
var_label <- c("Region", "Age", "Score")

df_variable <- data.frame(var, var_label)

Var <- c("A",NA,NA,NA,"B",NA,NA,"D",NA,NA)
value <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3)
value_label <- c("Midwest","East","West","SouthEast","10-19","20-29","30-39","A","B","C")

df_label <- data.frame(Var,value,value_label)
```

I have three data sets. First: raw, Second: variable name, Third: value labels
I want to create labels and levels for the raw data set from second and third data sets.

I have more than 100 variables, so I would like to automate as much as possible.

How would you automate the process? Thanks!

Comment: Could you be explicit about creation of levels: what values are levels and will they need an order. It would be helpful if you could explain the reasoning behind the data provided .

Comment: I have changed some vector names to give you more info. The data provided is just a simple example.